# Como puedo resolver de manera eficiente un programa para identificar a los trabajadores con bajo desempeño?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7, diccionarios

Se brinda una base de datos de trabajadores del departamento de marketing. Si el nivel de desempeño de un trabajador está por debajo de 50, se considera de bajo desempeño y se recomienda despedirlo.

Escribe una función que identifique a los trabajadores con bajo desempeño. Si se encuentra alguno, se debe mostrar "Se recomienda despedir al trabajador ". Luego, se elimina/n de la base de datos.

Aplica la función a la base de datos de trabajadores. Luego, muestra los nombres de los empleados restantes en una columna marcada como "Trabajadores de alto desempeño:".

**Base JSON**

```
staff = {
    'Juan': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 71
    },
    'Sofia': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 65
    },
    'Andres': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 49
    },
    'Romina': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 53
    }
}
```

**Salida**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo intente esto, pero no lo considera el sistema, muchas gracias por su ayuda

```
staff = {
    'Juan': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 71
    },
    'Sofia': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 65
    },
    'Andres': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 49
    },
    'Romina': {
        'cargo': 'marketing',
        'desempeño': 53
    }
}
def despedir(staff):
    for nombre in staff:
        if staff[nombre]["desempeño"]<50:
            print("Se recomienda despedir al trabajador", nombre)
            del staff[nombre]
despedir(staff)
print("Trabajadores con mejor desempeño:",*staff.keys(), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Acabo de tomar tu codigo y correrlo, está marcando correctamente que el trabajador a despedir es "andres". https://i.gyazo.com/7dd19330a046a7b7558374f445ee1618.png

Comment: @Excorpion pues sí pero eso está mal, que pasa si "Romina"  tiene un desempeño de 40? Simplemente no llegará a ese punto por el error

Comment: alguna forma de corregirlo?

Comment: El error se soluciona iterando en una copia del diccionario `for nombre in staff.copy()`

Comment: @Excorpion no es la solución.

Comment: podrias ser mas claro porfa

Comment: o planteralo como propuesta de solucion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce por que el diccionario es modificado mientras se ejecuta el `for`, esto ocasionado por la sentencia `del` que haces para eliminar al trabajador con menor rendimiento. La solución es simple y es iterar en una copia del diccionario para evitar que salte el error.

```py
def despedir(staff):
    for nombre in staff.copy(): #iteramos en una copia del diccionario
        if staff[nombre]["desempeño"]<50:
            print("Se recomienda despedir al trabajador", nombre)
            del staff[nombre]
despedir(staff)
print("Trabajadores con mejor desempeño:",*staff.keys(), sep="\n")
```

Esto modifica el diccionario original.

Comment: oki muchas gracias c: